# Error Flutter (186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this problem

***> E/flutter (15532): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at
> character 1) E/flutter (15532): 
>  E/flutter (15532): ^ E/flutter
> (15532):  E/flutter (15532): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail
> (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5) E/flutter (15532): #1
> _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271:9) E/flutter (15532): #2
> _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:936:22) E/flutter (15532): #3
> _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10) E/flutter (15532): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
> E/flutter (15532): #5      JsonCodec.decode
> (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41) E/flutter (15532): #6      jsonDecode
> (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10) E/flutter (15532): #7
> _LoginState.login (package:flutter_login/main.dart:35:18) E/flutter (15532):  E/flutter (15532):***

this is my code

```
    void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: login(),
  ));
}

class login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<login>{
  var email,password;
  final _key = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  check(){
    final form = _key.currentState;
    if(form.validate()){
      form.save();
      login();
    }
  }

  login() async{
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("link"),
        body: {
      "email" : email,
      "password" : password
    });
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
  }

  bool _secureText = false;
  showHide(){
    setState(() {
      _secureText = !_secureText;
    });
  }
```

can help me? pls

Comment: print `response.body`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me your Uri parsing is failing since you've passed **"link"** which is an invalid uri.

This is from the `Uri.parse` [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/parse.html):

> If the uri string is not valid as a URI or URI reference, a FormatException is thrown.